# transpose text on two sides of an equals (or other) sign

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I have a bunch of text of the form

```
grid = par1.grid;
M3d = par1.M3d;
alpha = par1.alpha;
gamma = par1.gamma;
```

and I want to transpose each line so the stuff to the right of the equals sign is now to the left of the equals sign and visa versa. So the text above would look as follows.

```
par1.grid = grid;
par1.M3d = M3d;
par1.alpha = alpha;
par1.gamma = gamma;
```

Is there an easy way to do this in emacs? I have figured out how to transpose words, but that doesn't seem like quite what I am looking for.

Edit: I am in matlab mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `C-M-%` (a.k.a. `M-x` `query-replace-regexp`) with regexp `\(.*\) = \(.*\);` and replacement `\2 = \1;`.

Comment: Tried this. Emacs says "Query replacing \(.*\) = \(.*\); with par1.grid = grid;: (? for help)". But then nothing seems to actually happen. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: `query-replace-regexp`  asks for confirmation before it actually replaces something. Have you tried pressing `?`? You can confirm for one occurrence by pressing SPACE or for all remaining occurrences by pressing `!`.  you can also use `replace-regexp` if you don't want to be asked for confirmation.

Comment: Although I do wonder about the prompt that you are seeing, in the prompt that I get I have backslashes before the parens.  I assume they were just eaten by StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the syntax entry for `=`, so that it is not a symbol constiuent or a word constituent. Assuming that `.` is a symbol constiuent or a word constituent and `;` is not, as in Emacs-Lisp mode, you can then just use `C-M-t` (transpose sexps) with point before (or after) the `=`.

E.g., in Emacs-Lisp mode, try `C-M-t` with point before the `=`, after evaluating this:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?= ".")
```

---

In whatever mode (assuming at least that letters have word-constituent syntax):

```
 (modify-syntax-entry ?=  ".") ; `=' is punctuation
 (modify-syntax-entry ?\; ".") ; `;' is punctuation
 (modify-syntax-entry ?.  "_") ; `.' is a symbol char
```

Comment: I think you'll also have to `(modify-syntax-entry ?. "w")` to get the OP's desired results. Otherwise you'll end up with `par1 = grid.grid;` etc.

Comment: No, not in Emacs-Lisp mode, where `.` is already a symbol-constituent char. Try it. That's why I stipulated the mode. In whatever mode you are, ensure that `.` is a symbol-constituent character (or a word-constituent char, as you mentioned).

Comment: Perhaps not in Emacs Lisp mode, but the OP's example doesn't look anything like lisp. I suppose without knowing the major mode the OP is using you have to pick one…

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the major mode in which you're editing: if your major mode uses SMIE to do its indentation, then `C-M-t` (with point on the = sign) should do the trick.